# Find version of Docker in OpenShift cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

How can I find out which version of Docker serves inside an OpenShift cluster when I am not able to execute `oc describe node` (presumably because mine is not an admin account). Or does OpenShift 3.11 use a well-known default version of Docker (similar to its well-known use of [Kubernetes 1.11](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/release_notes/ocp_3_11_release_notes.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per `OCP` is supported the specific `Docker` version.
The `Docker` version is `1.13.1` on `OCPv3.11`. Refer [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/host_preparation.html#installing-docker).